# Implementing a countdown with a UIProgressView and NSTimer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, nstimer, uiprogressview

I'm trying to implement a UIProgressView that continuously completes over a 10 second period.  I'm using NSTimer to try to achieve this, but I'm having a hard time figuring it out.  I've consulted the documentation on both UIProgressView and NSTimer, as well as other posted questions, please help me out if you can.

My current implementation doesn't update the UIProgress View at all.  The source code is excerpted below:

```
- (void)updateTimer:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    // sets timer
    [self setTimer:[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25f 
                                                  target:self 
                                                selector:@selector(updateTimer:) 
                                                userInfo:nil 
                                                repeats:YES]];
    float newProgress = [self.timeProgressView progress] + 0.025;
    [self.timeProgressView setProgress:newProgress animated:YES];
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is your UIProgressView connected to an IBOutlet or added as a subview somewhere ?

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
progressView.progress = 1;
    time = 1;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.1f
                                             target: self
                                           selector: @selector(updateTimer)
                                           userInfo: nil
                                            repeats: YES];

-(void) updateTimer
{
    if(time <= 0.0f)
    {
        //Invalidate timer when time reaches 0
        [timer invalidate];
    }
    else
    {
        time -= 0.01;
        progressView.progress = time;
    }
}
```

Comment: Elppa, thanks for responding!  Tried this just now, getting an around about the `time` variable, "Invalid Operands to binary expression" because it thinks `time` is a time object instead of a float, but I don't know how to use `time` in the updateTimer if I'm declaring it outside of the function.  Apologies if I'm missing something obvious, and thanks again for your help.

Comment: Is time declared as a float ?  You should probably set it to 1.0f initially.

Comment: Thanks. I've been messing around with this simple things for days. This approach is very simple and understandable. :)

Comment: Just one question. I want to play some sound when the timer reaches %25 of its end. How should I set this? I seem to be setting the wrong time for it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to setup the

```
[self setTimer:[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25f 
                                                  target:self 
                                                selector:@selector(updateTimer:) 
                                                userInfo:nil 
                                                repeats:YES]];
```

method outside the updateTimer, unless it gets called each 0.25 seconds.

or:

```
- (void)setupTimerWithTimer:(NSTimer *) timer{
[self setTimer:[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25f 
                                                      target:self 
                                                    selector:@selector(updateTimer) 
                                                    userInfo:nil 
                                                    repeats:YES]];
}

- (void)updateTimer{
   float newProgress = [self.timeProgressView progress] + 0.025;
   [self.timeProgressView setProgress:newProgress animated:YES];
}
```